# pymongo 2.8.1 install fails on OS 10.10.5

Tags: xcode, macos, mongodb

I have Mongo DB 3.0 local installed
I try to install pymongo 2.8.1 on OS X 10.10.5 with pip and get an error :

pip install pymongo==2.8.1
[...]

```
  Failed building wheel for pymongo
Failed to build pymongo
Installing collected packages: pymongo
  Running setup.py install for pymongo
Successfully installed pymongo-2.8.1
```

unsurprisingly, starting Django 1.8 later to connect to a local Mongo DB 3.0 fails miserably:
*AttributeError: module 'mongoengine.base' has no attribute 'DatabaseWrapper'*

I see that some install issued are linked to XCode (I have XCode 6.4) so I try :

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install pymongo==2.8.1
```

this workaround works for installing Fabric, but fails the same for pymongo

any idea of what I should do ? any XCode option ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally it appears that pymongo 2.8 does not install correctly - yet - with Python 3.5.

Creating a virtual environment with Python 3.4, the

```
pip install pymongo
```

succeeds